# Bounty "expiring soon" mismatched title in notification + appearing too early

Tags: bug, bounty, notifications

I got a notification saying that a bounty on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15086335/1313143) "is completed and will be auto-awarded in 24 hours", however it still had about 20 minutes to go when this appeared:

[image: bounty notification]

I don't remember ever getting this notification before when a bounty was not *actually* done yet - my question was still on the featured tab.

In any case, the title and the description are a bit mismatched. The title suggests it *will be complete soon* while the description says it's *completed*.